# Is there a way to reinitialize/refresh/reload an actual JavaScript/jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jrecorder

So, for a little backstory, I'm using the [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery) plugin for jQuery on a page that is dynamically fed some HTML via ajax. The user can record a .wav narration for an image in a slideshow, then (via ajax) flip over to another image, record another narration, rinse and repeat. End backstory!

The question itself is geared more towards jQ/JS in general, I believe.  When I run the 'record' function again, I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'jStartRecording'

This *only* appears when I switch to the second image and click "record". The first narration records just fine, and can be played back and whatnot with no issue.  I'm thinking I'm receiving the error because I need to re-initialize or reload the jRecorder plugin/method/function since I am trying to call jRecorder again using a different set of options (after switching to another image in the slideshow). Since I'm calling it again, it would appear that something hasn't completely loaded, or there is some sort of conflict between each instance of the plugin's operation.

**Bottom line: is there a way to reinitialize a jQuery plugin so it can be run again after dynamically switching parameters?**

Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely -- I don't know. Any insight from a different set of eyes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

**EDIT:** As requested, here's a little bit of code.  And [here is the plugin source](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/jRecorder.js).  Hope it helps!

`renderPanes()` is called each time the widget containing the narration recorder is refreshed with a new image's data. Obviously some things have been edited out for brevity and security.

```
function renderPanes(type, bucket_id) {
var isRecording = false;

$.getJSON( [endpoint] )
.done(function(json){
    [....]

    $.jRecorder({ 
            host : [endpoint],
            callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started(); },
            callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped(); },
            callback_activityLevel:          function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
            callback_activityTime:     function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },
            callback_finished_sending:     function(time){ callback_finished_sending() },
            swf_path : '/assets/js/jrecorder/jRecorder.swf',
    });

    $("#narration_play").click(function(){
        var audio = new Audio("[folder path]/"+bucket_id+".wav");
        audio.play();
    });

    $("#narration_record").click(function(){
        if (!isRecording) {
            $.jRecorder.record(30);
            $("#narration_record").html("<i class='icon-stop'></i> Stop");
            isRecording = true;
        } else {
            isRecording = false;
            $("#narration_record").html("<i class='icon-comment'></i> Record");
            $("#narration_play").removeClass('disabled');
            $.jRecorder.stop();
            $.jRecorder.sendData();
        }
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Show your code, it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Totally depends on how the plugin is authored, so the answer depends on the plugin.

Comment: @Barmar, I've gone ahead and added some code. Hopefully it's useful!

Comment: It looks like this plugin starts from scratch every time it's called. But it has some hard-coded default IDs for elements that it adds; if you don't override them in your initialization calls, you may end up with duplicates, and maybe that's causing the problem. Try supplying unique values for recorderlayout_id, recorder_id, and recorder_name (just increment a counter each time). Some plugins (e.g. most of jQuery UI) have a `.destroy` method to clean up, but this one doesn't.